# Redirect Joomla 1.5 URLs to wordpress in the same domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, joomla1.5

I have tried different methods to redirect Joomla 1.5 url to Wordpress page for following URLs in htaccess are not working.

Joomla old url 1)

> http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=55:psychiatry&catid=23:doctor&Itemid=48

Wordpress new url 1)

> http://www.example.com/psychiatry/

===================

Joomla old url 2)

> http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=52&Itemid=55

Wordpress New url 2)

> http://www.example.com/pharmaceutical/

Please help.

Thanks.
Mizan

Comment: In what is the parameter that your Joomla URLs are using to map to the Wordpress URLs? In 1) I can tell, but in 2) what is the key?

Comment: Is it possible to use this kind of rule 
=========================
Redirect 301 index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=55:psychiatry&catid=23:doctor&Itemid=48 index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=52&Itemid=55?
==========================
or 
==================
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} recordID=55
RewriteRule ^article-url-name\.php$ /destination-article-url/? [L,R=301]

Comment: Yes. Please see my solution below for both URLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these *.htaccess* rules for both cases:

These rules check for each parameter in the query string of the request. You can remove irrelevant parameters as needed.

First URL rewrite:

> ?option=com_content&view=article&id=55:psychiatry&catid=23:doctor&Itemid=48 --> /psychiatry/

```htaccess
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=article [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=55:psychiatry [NC] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} catid=23:doctor [NC] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Itemid=48 [NC] 
RewriteRule ^.*$ /psychiatry/? [L,R=301]
```

Second URL rewrite:

> ?option=com_content&view=article&id=52&Itemid=55 --> /pharmaceutical/

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_content [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=article [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=52 [NC] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Itemid=55 [NC] 
RewriteRule ^.*$ /pharmaceutical/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You can verify these rules, and tweak them, here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it is not redirected"? If the rule conditions are met, and the R=301 rewrite is applied, then a redirect is taking place. Are you talking about problems with your live server? If so, you may have other htaccess rules which are interfering. Please clarify.